# How do I split a blank string data using comma separated string and Show in msgbox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have two comma separated string. this String actually connected with database.

This the example of string what I actually want to use.
e.g.

```
 Dim value As String = "One,Two,Three"
 Dim mtr As String = ",,,"
```

I use the following code

```
Dim elements() As String = value.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim Q_MTR() As String = mtr.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

For i As Integer = 0 To elements.Length - 1

                MsgBox(elements(i) & " Mtr="& Q_MTR(i))

        Next
```

I want to show the Output Like:

```
"One Mtr= "
"Two Mtr= "
"Three Mtr= "
```

But I got Error

```
"Index was outside the bounds of the array."
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I solve this prblm? in VB.net.

Comment: Why do you even need the mtr string?  Just split value and add your "Mtr= " information to that.

Comment: Actually This data string connected with database. Because user did not give any data on "mtr" field it's automatically save ",,," if any data they input It can save like "500,600,," Then out can show like `"One Mtr=500 " "Two Mtr=600 " "Three Mtr= `

Comment: I think using Trim with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` doesn't work because " " isn't considered an empty entry. I need to do a normal split, then trim each item, then filter out the empty strings. But I don't know the process . Please help me.

Comment: Well, yes, you don't want to RemoveEmptyEntries on the MTR string.

Comment: Why not make the default value of the mtr string like this: `Dim mtr As String = ", , , "` ?

Comment: I use this code and it's work :)
`Dim Q_MTR() As String = mtr.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: In that case, I will use the field checking method so that no one can enter the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using Trim with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` doesn't work because " " isn't considered an empty entry. I need to do a normal split, then trim each item, then filter out the empty strings. So I change `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to `StringSplitOptions.None`.

I use this code and it's work :)

```
Dim Q_MTR() As String = mtr.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```